# Syntax issue with UPDATE query using WHERE and LIKE

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update an empty field in my table to show "Spray Guns Service Kit" if the product code field has "ASPASK" in it.

This is what I have tried thus far:

```
UPDATE Products
SET field7 = 'Spray Gun Service Kit'
WHERE ProductCode LIKE '%ASPASK%' ;
```

Access keeps telling me I am updating 0 rows when I should be updating 100s. However, when I change the code to it works but only with one product:

```
UPDATE Products
SET field7 = 'Spray Gun Service Kit'
WHERE ProductCode = 'ASPASK001' ;
```

I haven't used Access or SQL since 2015 so I am a tad out of touch with the syntax so I'm certain the issue is with how I am using the LIKE statement

Comment: Doesn't Access have * instead of %? Or similar?

Comment: Just tried it in MySQL 5.7.34 and it works...

Comment: MySQL isn't MS Access...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS-Access uses `*` instead of the `%` wildcard character:

```
UPDATE Products
SET field7 = 'Spray Gun Service Kit'
WHERE ProductCode LIKE '*ASPASK*' ;
```